# The 'dspace' tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I've noticed the [dspace](/questions/tagged/dspace) tag, which has just 10 uses at this point, is used for both the [DSpace open source digital repository](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSpace) (7 of 10 instances), the [dSPACE mechantronic hardware and software](http://www.dspace.com/en/inc/home.cfm), and perhaps a [MATLAB function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493867/matlab-java-string-conversion)? I'm not 100% sure on the latter.

In any case, I thought it would be a good time to sort out this tag with such few instances. Introduce separate tags for the different **dspace** domains, remove it all together, eliminate some uses, etc.?